# How do i turn myself invisible including armor and items im holding?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

im making a map and for it to work i used some commands to give the player a câmera system to use , but the system teleports the player into the câmera spots for it to watch . 
The problem is that the player armor and items he is holding are still visible.
There is any command to turn both invisible as well?

Comment: Does Spectator mode not work for what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: no because i need the player to choose in the hotbar what câmera he wants to see , the spectator mode dos not have inventory or hotbar.

Comment: You could in theory make every item invisible using a resource pack, but then it would also be invisible in the hotbar.

Answer (score 1):

Armor and any items you are holding cannot be turned invisible. Downloading Mods would be the only way to get them all invisible.

Comment: Do you know of any specific mod that would do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the /replaceitem command to temporarily transfer the items out of the player’s hand and/or armour slots?